# CSS selector with multiple classes

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

When an element can have one or more classes

```
<div class="questionItem format"/>
```

or

```
<div class="questionItem"><div>
```

How do you find all the div's with the `questionItem`, regardless of the other classes?

Comment: you mean in CSS? or something else? CSS it would be `.questionItem` just like normal.. or `$('.questionItem')` for jQuery

Answer (score 4):

In jQuery, I presume?

```
var qItems = $('.questionItem');
```

Answer (score 3):

This is simple,

```
$('.questionItem')
```

will return all of the elemnts which have the class `questionItem`

while:

```
$('.questionItem.format')
```

will return all of the elements that have BOTH classes `questionItem` and `format`

Read up about [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) and [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) on the jQuery documentation

Answer (score 2):

If you want all the div's:  `$('div.questionItem')`

Answer (score -3):

found the solution:

```
filter(".questionItem")
```

I had been using:

```
filter("[class='questionItem']")
```